# Получение поля SET из БД в java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Как получить поле типа SET из БД mysql в java?

Comment: Получайте SET-поле как маску (числовой контекст), для этого просто прибавьте к нему ноль: `SELECT 0+set_field AS set_mask, ...` Если же хотите получить список (разделитель - запятая) соответствующих битам маски литералов - получайте SET-поле как строковое.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL тип `SET` он же `ENUM`, он же перечисляемый тип, в Java (точнее в JDBC) напрямую не поддерживается - то есть нет прямой трансляции `SET` в Java `Enum`. Значения можно просто читать как `String`:

```
ResultSet rs;
String value=rs.getString("SetColumn");
```

Далее полученное значение можно уже мапить на Java `Enum` примерно так:

```
MyEnum myEnumVal =  MyEnum.valueOf(value);
```

Comment: *MySQL тип SET он же ENUM, он же перечисляемый тип* Ну ерунды-то не говорите! `SET` - это масочный тип (класса много-ко-много). Хранит набор нескольких значений из списка допустимых (определённых при создании поля), количество которых ограничено 64 штуками.  `ENUM` - это перечисляемый тип, аналог встроенной таблицы-справочника (класса один-ко-много). Хранит строго одно значение из списка допустимых, количество которых ограничено числом 255 минус количество определённых ENUM-значений.

Comment: Ну не специалист я по мускулу :) С точки зрения JDBC это один и тот же тип

Comment: *С точки зрения JDBC это один и тот же тип* Если поле `SET` определено как `SET('one','two')`, в него можно записать одно из значений `('one')`, `('two')` или `('one','two')` (а также пустую строку или NULL). Если же аналогично определено поле `ENUM`, то в него можно записать все одиночные значения, но нельзя записать значение `('one','two')`. Если в JDBC, как Вы говорите, они неразличимы, значит, тип `SET` **нельзя** маппить напрямую, только на числовой или строковый контент, иначе при преобразовании произойдёт потеря данных.

Comment: С точки зрения JDBC оба этих типа просто `String`, в случае с `ENUM` будет получена одиночная строка, а в случае `SET` строка где значения разделены запятыми

Comment: *С точки зрения JDBC оба этих типа просто String* А тогда что автор-то хотел? я что-то вообще не понимаю...

Comment: Ему нужно было понять во что это поле можно было смаппить (или принять) на стороне Java